# UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen allow interaction with view controller below

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a home page view controller. On top of that, I have presented a view controller that acts like a drawer, and moved the view of that controller mostly offscreen. The modal drawer view controller has a navigation bar. You can see most of the home page view underneath the drawer. When clicked, that "drawer" opens up to become fullscreen, including the navigation bar.

In ios7, I set the **presenting** view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to be `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. In ios8, I set the **presented** view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to be `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`. This is how it must be done.

```
    if ([PCDeviceManager isDeviceiOS7]) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    } else {
         projectsVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    }

    [self presentViewController:projectsVC animated:NO completion:^{
        CGRect frame = projectsVC.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 45;
        [projectsVC.view setFrame:frame];
    }];
```

In both ios7 and 8, the sliding transition is exactly what I want, the nav bar goes all the way to the top of the screen, underneath the status bar.

However, in ios7, I am able to interact with the subviews in the home page view controller's view. In ios8, I cannot... I need to be able to interact with a table view on the home page. The drawer is not covering the table, but they are in different view controllers.

It is working in ios7- I can interact with the table on the home screen. How can I make this work on ios8?

EDIT: Images of the drawer open and closed:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p3bqpygyoe1fdi/drawer.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sml60bi0iqxmwzj/drawer%20open.png?dl=0